# The action 'create' could not be found for Admin::UsersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am stuck with this issue, and i am not able to identify the problem. I am trying to add a user from admin section. Hence I have created a custom user controller, which calls the devise model. And I am trying to insert and update values using custom forms.

Controller

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  layout 'admin-layout'

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit({ roles: [] }, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end

  def index
    @user = User.all
  end


  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new
    if @user.save
        redirect_to :action => "index"
    else
        render :action => "new" 
    end     
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes
        redirect_to :action => "index"
    else
        render :Action => "update"  
    end 
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to ::Action => "index"
  end
end
```

View File

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <h2>Create New User</h2>
        <%= form_for @user, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :email, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => "Enter Email", :required => "true" %>
        <%= f.text_field :password, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => "Enter Password", :required => "true" %>
        <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => "Enter Password Again", :required => "true" %>

        <p>Roles:</p>
        <% for r in Role.all %>
        <%= check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", r.id %>
        <%= r.name %>
        <% end %><br/>
        <%= f.submit "Create", :class=>"btn btn-primary" %>

        <% end %>
    </div>  
<div>
```

Routes

```
admin_users GET    /admin/users(.:format)                admin/users#index
            POST   /admin/users(.:format)                admin/users#create
```

Can any1 please point me out where am I making a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined `new`, `create` etc. methods as `protected`, they need to be public if you want them to be recognized as actions.

BTW, in Ruby, if you have collection `Role.all`, it's much more readable to iterate over this with `each` instead of `for` (which is rarely used here):

```
<% Role.all.each do |r| %>
```

Comment: I removed protected but now i get ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Comment: @Arun use [strong params](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) then. Your code seems to have more issues - why don't you go through tutorial before you start coding in Rails? There are many of them.

Comment: yeah i know strong parameters, i want to permit roles params, according to https://github.com/plataformatec/devise i have included configure_permitted_parameters method.